# Exportar paquetes con "dbms_metadata.get_ddl"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

Estoy exportando paquetes usando `dbms_metadata.get_ddl`. Por ejemplo:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PACKAGE_BODY','NOMBRE_PAQ','SCHEMA_NA‌​ME') from dual;
```

Pero al generar el spool con el código del paquete, se genera una línea en blanco antes del `CREATE OR REPLACE...`.

¿Cómo puedo eliminar la línea en blanco en la extracción?

Intenté seteando:

```
DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'PRETTY', true)
```

... pero no funciona.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir un ejemplo concreto que nos sirva para reproducir tu problema?

Comment: Cuando extraigo un paquete, por ej: select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PACKAGE_BODY','NOMBRE_PAQ','SCHEMA_NAME') from dual; obtengo el codigo del paquete pero antes de CREATE OR REPLACE hay una linea en blanco, podeis ejecutarlo y abrid el clob, ahi vereis dichos espacios en blanco al inicio

Answer (score 0):

En efecto, es fastidioso, pero `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` siempre te devuelve un resultado que comienza con el carácter para una nueva línea (ascii 10).

Si lo quieres quitar, puedes usar [`SUBSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions181.htm#SQLRF06114) para que te devuelva todo salvo el primer carácter:

```
select substr(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PACKAGE_BODY','NOMBRE_PAQ','SCHEMA_NA‌​ME'), 2)
  from dual;
```

O puedes probar con [`TRIM`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions219.htm#SQLRF06149):

```
select trim(leading chr(10) from dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PACKAGE_BODY','NOMBRE_PAQ','SCHEMA_NA‌​ME'))
  from dual;
```

Tal vez usar el `TRIM` condicional es mejor, por si hubiera alguna circunstancia donde el resultado no comenzara con una nueva línea.

[**Demostración**](http://rextester.com/AQLW92866).